# why my .dae file dont show texture and animation in three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js, textures, collada

i have these files :
[Karma model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jlfxZyVvcK0ZQcxyrG7tx2ix3mInQrjA)
and when i launch .html file , it shows .dae file but without texture and animation , what i need to do ?

Comment: This model doesn't appear correctly in Blender or QuickLook for me, either. I tried importing to Blender, correcting the texture, and exporting out as glTF. This was as close as I could get, I think the animation needs some manual adjustment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcjB3.gif

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a web server?
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally